# LLVM stdin/stdout/stderr

Tags: llvm

How does one declare `stdin`, `stout`, and `stderr` (preferably the C versions) in LLVM? I am trying to use some stdio functions in a toy language I am creating. One such function was `fgets`:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

In order to use that I needed `stdin`. So I wrote some LLVM API code to generate the definition of FILE that I found, and declared `stdin` a external global. The code generated this:

```
%file = type { i32, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, %marker*, %file*, i32, i32, i64, i16, i8, [1 x i8], i8*, i64, i8*, i8*, i8*, i8*, i64, i32, [20 x i8] }
%marker = type { %marker*, %file*, i32 }

@stdin = external global %file*
```

However, when I ran the resulting module, it gave me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_stdin", referenced from:
    _main in cc9A5m3z.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Apparently, what I wrote didn't work. So my question is what do I have to write in the LLVM API to declare `stdin`, `stout`, and `stderr` for functions like `fgets` in something like a toy language compiler?

Comment: You can write helper functions in C which will return stdin/stdout/stderr and link them with your program.

Comment: I'll try that, though I would prefer to just use what the LLVM API gives us to do it, if I can.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I found an answer to my question. After some intense searching I found a way to get the `stdin` stream without having to make a C extension: `fdopen` and making `FILE` an opaque struct.

```
FILE* fdopen (int fildes, const char *mode)
```

When fdopen is passed 0 for a file descriptor (`fildes`) It returns the `stdin` stream. Using the LLVM API, I generated the following LLVM assembly:

```
%FILE = type opaque
declare %FILE* @fdopen(i32, i8*)
@r = constant [2 x i8] c"r\00"
```

Then I was able to retrieve `stdin` with this call statement:

```
%stdin = call %FILE* @fdopen(i32 0, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([2 x i8]* @r, i32 0, i32 0))
```

Comment: maybe you could also point out in your answer that the C99 standard doesn't specify 'stderr' & co. to be a global extern.

Answer (score 5):

If you use functions like `putchar`, `printf`, `gets`, `strtol`, `puts`, `fflush` you won't need `stdin` and `stdout`. I wrote a toy compiler and those were enough for I/O with strings and integers. `fflush` is called with null and `stdout` gets flushed.

```
%struct._IO_FILE = type opaque
declare i32 @fflush(%struct._IO_FILE*)
...
call i32 @fflush(%struct._IO_FILE* null)
...
```

Comment: this answer is basically a long winded "don't do it!"

Comment: `gets` was removed, so not sure how to do it without stdin anymore https://libc.llvm.org/stdio.html

Answer (score 1):

It is platform specific. Sometimes stdin is macro to different symbol name.

On Android, for example, stdin is `#define  stdin   (&__sF[0])`.

For Microsoft Visual C++, stdin is `#define stdin  (&__iob_func()[0])`

So you really need to look into your platform `stdio.h` header to figure that out.

Comment: So, what do I then need to write in the LLVM API to declare stdin, in, for example, a toy language compiler?

Comment: You need to look into your platfrom `stdio.h` header to figure it out what symbol/declaration to use for stdio, so it links correctly with C runtime library you will use.